# MongoDB C# Driver Unit Testing: Mock .AsQueryable()

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing

I am using .NET 4.7.2 and latest MongoDB.
I heavily use the drivers support for LINQ.

This is what a standard usage in my repos looks like:

```
 var strategies = this.mongoClient.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Strategy>("strategies")
                .AsQueryable(new AggregateOptions { Hint = MongoDbIndexCreator.RunningStrategies })
                .Where(x => x.IsRunning == true);
```

I found ways to mock `IMongoQueryable` and `GetCollection`but static extension `.AsQueryable()` really is a problem for me.
Does anybody have a solution for this? How do MongoDB LINQ users unit test their applications?
Ideally I would not bother with mocking at all and rather use some kind of in-memory set up? But I am afraid there is no such thing for MongoDB?

A wrapper / abstraction does not help me either:

```
  public interface IMongoDbProvider
    {
        IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>();

        IMongoQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>();
    }
```

Users of `IMongoDbProvider` still depend on either `IMongoCollection` or `IMongoQueryable` to leverage database features.

Comment: I don't think so, but the key point that is a bad practice to mock classes that you don't own, you should mock your wrapper around this class

Comment: yes but at some point I need to actually return an IMongoQueryable<T> which I can't figure out how to do. at the end I cannot create an abstraction around IMongoQueryable<T>